# Global array loses its data once it leaves the function it's populated within. Why?

Tags: arrays, swift

I've got a global array called tableArray. I have a function called parseJSON.

Within parseJSON I make a URLSession call to a url and gather a bunch of data which is stored inside the tableArray array.  If I print the global array by doing 'print(self.tableArray)' I see the expected results in my console, if I print the array in the viewDidLoad function after I've ran the parseJSON function it prints an empty array '[]'.  All my code is below, could somebody firstly: Explain why the array behaves as it does, and secondly correct the problem.

Thanks in advance!

```
var tableArray = [[String:Any]] ()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //Any additional setup after load
    parseJSON()
    //This prints an empty array ?
    print(self.tableArray)
}

func parseJSON() {
    let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.1.100/api/DisplayMenu.php")
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    //typealias JSONDictionary = [String:Any]

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {(data, response, error) in

        guard error == nil else {
            print("returned error")
            return
        }

        guard let content = data else {
            print("No data")
            return
        }

        let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content)) as? [[String: Any]] ?? []

        if let array = json as? [[String:Any]] {
            self.tableArray = array
        }
        //This prints the data as expected
        print(self.tableArray)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Have a look into asynchronous programming, it has been asked about million times here on SO. In summary, you get the data from a network request, which takes a long time to execute and you are trying to access values before they would be meaningful.

Comment: Nothing is lost. Your `print` in `viewDidLoad` is called long before the data is loaded. There's nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: ALMOST nothing :-)  other than the async bit

Comment: Thanks so much for the responses, makes total sense now.

Comment: The asynchronous comments are correct. Unrelated, you should move your setting of `tableArray` inside the `DispatchQueue.main.async` closure ... you don’t want to change your properties, like `tableArray`, from a background thread.

Comment: I'd like to mark one of the answers in here as correct, not sure how.  Thanks Rob for the additional pointer.